# Getting random rows in Big Query with different limit?

Tags: google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I have the following queries :

- SELECT * FROM `datafusiontest-2897325.mergedquery.test_table LIMIT 10
- SELECT * FROM `datafusiontest-2897325.mergedquery.test_table LIMIT 100
- SELECT * FROM `datafusiontest-2897325.mergedquery.test_table LIMIT 10000

I am getting a different top result for each query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your query is not specifying an order, it is normal for results to be different each time - they are returning random rows from your table which meet the qualifying criteria.

To get the same top n returned you should add an `ORDER BY` clause, for example:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `datafusiontest-2897325.mergedquery.test_table`
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 10
```